# How to multiply each element of two nested lists?

Tags: python

There are 2 nested lists, I want to multiply items at corresponding positions, so that the output is `[[9, 16, 21], [24, 25, 24], [21, 16, 9]]`.
I use the program below.  It works, but it seems too complex.  Is that any quick way to do it?  Is there any library to quickly perform such a task?

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
n = []
for i in range(3):
    m = []
    for j in range(3):
        m.append(a[i][j] * b[i][j])
    n.append(m)
print(n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `zip` twice:

```
a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b=[[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
result = [[j*k for j, k in zip(c, d)] for c, d in zip(a, b)]
```

Output:

```
[[9, 16, 21], [24, 25, 24], [21, 16, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the lists to the multiplication operator:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import mul
print(list(map(list, map(partial(map, mul), a, b))))
```

Output:

```
[[9, 16, 21], [24, 25, 24], [21, 16, 9]]
```

If you're using Python 2.x you can skip the conversion to lists as well:

```
print map(partial(map, mul), a, b)
```